# How to push changes from branch A to branch B without removing new changes from B branch git (no merge)

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, sourcetree

I am working with git since a long time. The challenge am facing now is bit confusing. My problem is managing repository with different releases of the application.

I am working on an application in which i have to release several modules of the application and i will have to continue development in proceeding modules without waiting for the testing issues of previous modules. So I have created different branches for each module and working on them leaving the old branch to a position where the changes for that module is completed. Its ok but the problem is when the tester will give issues on old module i will have to fix those particular issues on the old branch and those fixes should also reflect on new working branch and future branches of source codes. And i will have to give a build with fixes of old branch only till the old branch task target without the new changes from new branch.

I am using source tree mac application to manage my repository. Is there any way to achieve this task. What i am doing right now is simultaneously modifying source codes of 2 repositories for single issue fix and i am afraid if i have to do this for 3 repositories which is horrible because i am about to finish the 2nd module also. I hope there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cherry-pick.

```
branch_a : A - B - C <- tip
branch_b : D - E - F <- tip
```

To cherry-pick commit E from branch_b to branch_a, do:

```
git checkout branch_a
git cherry-pick E
```

And you will end up with:

```
branch_a : A - B - C - E' <- HEAD
branch_b : D - E - F <-tip
```

Where `E'` is identical to `E` but on top of `C`.

Comment: this seems to be the solution. So i have to do this every time by checking out the branch_a whenever i push something in old branch_b?

Comment: Well, if there is no natural relation between the branches so you can uplift one to the other then i guess you will have to cherry-pick the commits you actually want to move over to the branch

Comment: i tried it practically and seems very easy but we have to track it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cherry pick commits using https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: i have read the description and some details in the page for above link. I could not figure out how to do that with different branches. can you explain some brief?